# Excel VBA can't save file

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code but I have a problem saving a file.

```
Private o As Integer

Public Sub Procedure1()
   o = 1
End Sub
Sub dural()
Location = Sheets("uitleg").Range("A2").Value
Totallocation = Location & "\"
Debug.Print (Totallocation)
checkNum = Sheets("FunBelgium").Range("A1").Value
Debug.Print (checkNum)
lRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row 'finds last row, assumes contiguous data
j = 1 'first row for your output

For i = 1 To lRow
    If Range("A" & i).Value = checkNum Then

        Sheets("Output").Range("A" & j & ":N" & j).Value = Sheets("FunBelgium").Range("A" & i & ":N" & i).Value

        Rows([i]).EntireRow.Delete

        j = j + 1 'advances output row counter if checkNum is found

    End If
Next
    o = o + 1
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        Sheets("Export").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Copy
        Thisfile = ActiveSheet.Range("J2").Value
        With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            .Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlValues
            .PasteSpecial xlFormats
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Totallocation & Thisfile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
        'ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\sgouman\Downloads\Bernd\" & Thisfile & ".csv"

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Sheets("FunBelgium").Activate
        If Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
            Sheets("Output").Cells.ClearContents
            Exit Sub
        Else:
            Debug.Print ("niet leeg")
            Sheets("Output").Cells.ClearContents
            j = 0
            Call dural
        End If
End Sub
```

So the debug for totallocation is this:
C:\Users\sgouman\Downloads\Bernd\

But I get an 1004 error. If I just manually copy in that file location in the activeworkbook.saveas it works fine.

Comment: hi. whats the value of Thisfile at the time of save ?

Comment: @LuisCurado something like OIR-1254 but when I do this: 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\sgouman\Downloads\Bernd\" & Thisfile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True It works fine.

Comment: in the example u refer that with 'ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\sgouman\Downloads\Bernd\" & Thisfile & ".csv" it works, but on the last coment u refer  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\sgouman\Downloads\Bernd\" & Thisfile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True.

does it work with booth ?

Comment: Try putting `& ".csv",` after `Thisfile,`

Comment: On the example the first one you mention is greyed out because I used that earlier but with the fileformat works if I manually putt in the location. If I also manually putt in the location in the one you mentioned it works too.

Comment: What I noticed is when I press f8 and loop trough the code everything works as it should be. When I start the rode using the play icon on top it gives that error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the issue:

```
Totallocation = Location & "\"
```

Please replace by this:

```
Totallocation = Location & "\\"
```

Reason: the "\" character is a special character, giving another meaning to the next one (e.g. "\n" is newline, "\t" is tab character, ...).

I tried on my PC and there everything is working fine, please debug your VBA code to the "Save" line, and in the immediate window, launch following commands and let us know the results:

```
?totalLocation
?ThisFile
?totalLocation & Thisfile
```

This should show you what the filenames look like.

By the way, are you sure your directory is not read-only? Are you even sure that this is the line, causing the issue?

Comment: Now even with normal line so like this: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\sgouman\Downloads\testing\" & Thisfile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True or this ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\sgouman\Downloads\testing\\" & Thisfile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True It gives the same error.

Comment: What I noticed is when I press f8 and loop trough the code everything works as it should be. When I start the rode using the play icon on top it gives that error.

Comment: @klaas123: I've updated my answer, based on some own testing. At my PC, everything is working fine.

Comment: For some reason when I press start nothing works. Normally it copy's stuff to another sheet but nothing happens.